# EF Migrations - Allow Data Loss on a single migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

In the `Configuration` of Entity Framework migrations, you can add this line:

```
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

which will allow data loss when (e.g.) dropping columns.

Is there a way to do this only on specific migrations?

i.e. I wouldn't want to have this permanently set, but if I scaffold a migration that has data loss, I'd like to have to manually go into that migration and do something like this:

```
public partial class removing_date_time : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        //...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot do that**.

B'cos that property is for the **automatic migration**.You cannot use it with Code Based Migration (i.e with `Up()` and `Down()`).That property belongs to the `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class.

You can read more about it here : [**AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationdatalossallowed(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: It would be nice if you could. I use Automatic Migrations, but I don't want to accidentally incur data loss. So I want that switch off. But occasionally, I need to have a migration that loses data.  So I'd like to be forced to scaffold the migration explicitly, and then enable data loss just for that migration. Make sense? This is not possible?

Comment: Yes,it is **not possible**. You cannot do that with migration scripts.